# Higher Order Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I'd like to know if there is a higher order (third order, fourth order, ...) analogues of Riemann curvature tensor or other related notions of curvature on vector bundles.

**Background**

Given a smooth vector bundle $E \rightarrow M$, one way to define a connection on it is to give a linear map:
$$\nabla: \Gamma(M,\wedge^p T^*M \otimes E) \rightarrow \Gamma(M, \wedge^{p+1} T^*M \otimes E)$$
such that for $p=0$, $\nabla(\varphi \xi) = d \varphi \cdot \xi + \varphi \cdot \nabla \xi$ for each smooth function $\varphi$ and $\xi \in \Gamma(M,E)$, and extend this notion to higher order $E$-valued forms.

A more down-to-earth notion of directional derivative can be obtained from the above definition as:
$$\nabla_X \xi = \langle \xi, \nabla X\rangle $$
for $\xi \in \Gamma(M,E)$ and $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ being contraction of a covector with a vector.

From a connection $\nabla$, we get
$$\nabla^2 := \nabla \circ \nabla : \Gamma(M,E) \rightarrow \Gamma(M, \wedge^2 T^*M \otimes E)$$
which we may define as curvature because for $E = TM$, it satisfies the following identity:
$$(\nabla^2 Z)(X,Y) = R(X,Y)Z = ([\nabla_X, \nabla_Y] - \nabla_{[X,Y]})Z$$
Therefore studying Riemann curvature tensor $R$ is equivalent to studying $\nabla^2$.

The obvious generalization is to ask: can we ascribe meaning to $\nabla^3, \nabla^4, \cdots$, and associate meaningful quantities to them? For example, we may ask if there is an expression of the form:
$$(\nabla^k Y)(X_1, \cdots X_k) = \sum_i P_i(\nabla_{Q_{i,1}(X_1, \cdots X_k)}, \cdots \nabla_{Q_{i,m}(X_1, \cdots X_k)})Y$$
where $P,Q$ are (noncommutative) polynomials.

Note: this question is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564309/do-torsion-and-curvature-have-higher-order-analogues), which didn't have any answer.

Comment: My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347082/what-comes-after-the-curvature-tensor-in-higher-derivatives/3240908#3240908) might be relevant. For what is it worth (I didn't write this there), $({\rm d}^{\nabla})^4\psi(X,Y,Z,W)$ is a combination of $6$ terms of the form $R^\nabla(X,Y)\circ R^\nabla(Z,W)\psi$, which further illustrates that $R^\nabla$ already carries the information you want.

Comment: Also, I organized these calculations [here](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/cov_ext.pdf)